# How do you sum on a list of objects in a java 8 stream

Tags: java, list, java-8, java-stream

In C# I had this

```
List<Learner> Learners;
double learnerSum = this.Learners.Sum(learner => learner.Predicted * learner.Alpha);
```

I want to do the same in java 8. I get as far as

```
double learnerSum = this.Learners.stream()...
```

It seems i need a reduce but all the examples are on simple arrays of integers.  what am i missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a `DoubleStream` from a `Stream`, and use the method `sum` to get the sum.

```
double learnerSum = Learners.stream()
    .mapToDouble(l -> l.Predicted * l.Alpha).sum();
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work unless there's a better solution.

```
Learners.stream().collect(Collectors.summingDouble(learner -> learner.Predicted * learner.Alpha ));
```

Comment: This works, though the "reducing" collectors are really only there for use as the downstream of another collector, like groupingBy.  Mapping to a DoubleStream and calling sum() is preferable.